# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given string value: { "In last 7 days" : 19 } cannot be transformed to Json object

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, criteria, entitymanager

Hi I have a json field in my postgresql table and I am using criteria api to read it's value but I am getting above error message. I have followed the steps mentioned in https://vladmihalcea.com/map-string-jpa-property-json-column-hibernate/

My code -

pojo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name", schema = "test")
@TypeDef(
        name = "jsonb",
        typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class
)
public class Test implements Serializable {
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "details", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    MyClass myclass;

}
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private String days;
    private String value;

    public String getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(String days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return '{' + '"' + days + '"' + ':' + value + '}';
    }
}
```

MyDTO -

```
public class MyDTO {
    @JsonProperty("details")
    MyClass myClass;

}
```

criteria API :

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Test> test = criteriaQuery.from(Test.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.lower(test.get("test_id")), testId.toLowerCase()));
criteriaQuery.select(test.get("myclass"));
List<Object[]> result = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

error stacktrace:

```
Severe Error: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given string value: { "In last 7 days" : 19 } cannot be transformed to Json object
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JacksonUtil.fromString(JacksonUtil.java:20)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor.fromString(JsonTypeDescriptor.java:52)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor.wrap(JsonTypeDescriptor.java:75)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.AbstractJsonSqlTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(AbstractJsonSqlTypeDescriptor.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultRow(QueryLoader.java:457)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(QueryLoader.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1562)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
    at com.test.getTestDetail(ServiceV2.java:108)
    at com.test.ControllerV2.fetchDetail(ControllerV2.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
    at com.test.ControllerV2Test.testDetails(ControllerV2Test.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
`
```

Answer (score 3):

The JSON is valid.  (I checked, and I was surprised to see that a key can be any JSON string.  See http://www.json.org. )

Based on the stacktrace, I think that the real problem is that Jackson is attempting to use

```
  { "In last 7 days" : 19 }
```

to create a `MyClass` instance.  The problem is that `MyClass` has no field that corresponds to the key `"In last 7 days"`.  The fields are `days` and `value`.

You will have to deal with that by creating a custom object mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make sure to implement Serializable for the MyDTO class as you are using the MyClass inside it. It

Answer (score 0):

The issue is no field that maps to the key "In last 7 days". We can use cusmtom mapper if we wan to skip some fields

https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-types-customize-jackson-objectmapper/